# Fastest way to compute e^x?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

What is the fastest way to compute e^x, given x can be a floating point value.

Right now I have used the python's math library to compute this, below is the complete code where in `result = -0.490631 + 0.774275 * math.exp(0.474907 * sum)` is the main logic, rest is file handling code which the question demands.

```
import math
import sys

def sum_digits(n):
   r = 0
   while n:
       r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
   return r

def _print(string):
    fo = open("output.txt", "w+")
    fo.write(string)
    fo.close()

try:
    f = open('input.txt')
except IOError:
    _print("error")
    sys.exit()
data = f.read()
num = data.split('\n', 1)[0]
try:
   val = int(num)
except ValueError:
    _print("error")
    sys.exit()

sum = sum_digits(int(num))
f.close()

if (sum == 2):
    _print("1")
else:
    result = -0.490631 + 0.774275 * math.exp(0.474907 * sum)
    _print(str(math.ceil(result)))
```

The rvalue of `result` is the equation of curve (which is the solution to a programming problem) which I derived from `wolfarm-mathematica` using my own data set.

But this doesn't seem to pass the par criteria of the assessment !

I have also tried the newton-raphson way but the convergence for larger x is causing the problem, other than that, calculating the natural log `ln(x)` is a challenge there again !

I don't have any language constraint so any solution is acceptable. Also if the python's math library is fastest as some of the comments says then can anyone give an insight on the time complexity and execution time of this program, in short the efficiency of the program ?

Comment: What is the question? `math.exp` does calculate e^x about as fast as it gets (it normally uses your floating point processor, then wraps the result as a Python float), but this certainly isn't a complete example (`sum` is a function) and we don't know what fails (the test isn't described). Then out of the blue a question about bitwise operations, which rarely mix with floating point. If you do have working code, this is unlikely to be the level that optimization can help at.

Comment: Most of automated "check-code" tools verifies if _time complexity_ of your algorithm match given criteria, not absolute time of execution. Re-think your algorithm as complete solution, do not focus on micro-optimizations.

Comment: You ask for "in python" and then you say you don't have any language constraint. Huh?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski `result = -0.490631 + 0.774275 * math.exp(0.474907 * sum) ` is the only logic and the `result` is the answer, so what is the time complexity, I suppose O(n) but then why the "check-code" labels it as poor ?

Comment: How can I describe the test which i do not know ? As i have told you, the online coding contests does not tell you all these things, it just gives you the result as "Good, Poor, Average, Below Average" @YannVernier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the exponential curve math is accurate in this code, but it certainly isn't the slow point.

First, you read the input data in one `read` call. It does have to be read, but that loads the entire file. The next step takes the first line only, so it would seem more appropriate to use `readline`. That split itself is O(n) where n is the file size, at least, which might include data you were ignoring since you only process one line.

Second, you convert that line into an `int`. This probably requires Python's long integer support, but the operation could be O(n) or O(n^2). A single pass algorithm would multiply the accumulated number by 10 for each digit, allocating one or two new (longer) longs each time.

Third, `sum_digits` breaks that long int down into digits again. It does so using division, which is expensive, and two operations as well, rather than using `divmod`. That's O(n^2), because each division has to process every higher digit for each digit. And it's only needed because of the conversion you just did.

Summing the digits found in a string is likely easier done with something like `sum(int(c) for c in l if c.isdigit())` where `l` is the input line. It's not particularly fast, as there's quite a bit of overhead in the digit conversions and the sum might grow large, but it does make a single pass with a fairly tight loop; it's somewhere between O(n) and O(n log n), depending on the length of the data, because the sum might grow large itself.

As for the unknown exponential curve, the existence of an exception for a low number is concerning. There's likely some other option that's both faster and more accurate if the answer's an integer anyway.

Lastly, you have at least four distinct output data formats: error, 2, 3.0, 3e+20. Do you know which of these is expected? Perhaps you should be using formatted output rather than `str` to convert your numbers.

One extra note: If the data is really large, processing it in chunks will definitely speed things up (instead of running out of memory, needing to swap, etc). As you're looking for a digit sum your size complexity can be reduced from O(n) to O(log n).

Comment: Looks like the arbitrary constants injected are a variant of Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers. The exception coded in breaks the sequence early on, though, and the limited precision of floats may come into play, if we expect the program to be tested on large input.

Comment: An integer is expected as output that's why the `math.ceil()` is used. I would appreciate an optimized code in the language of your choice

Comment: Then it almost certainly expects an exact number. You should stop using floating point at all, and do the Fibonacci calculation in longs. It may still be useful to do it in fewer steps than the sum though; one idea is once per digit, with matrices of how many times F(i-n) and F(i-n-1) are included. The concept could be done once per block also but the small range of digits makes a lookup table practical.

Comment: I have used mathematica to find the equation of curve, please refer the link I have used to find the equation of curve and to carry on with the further things https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147456/finding-the-equation-of-curve the inputs are the values I have found by coding the problem, but since I used recursion in it, the stack was overflowing hence I had to find a generic way to find it for larger n.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the part that the input data set is creating a Fibonacci Series, I found a code to compute f(n) in O(log n ) time.

Comment: The challenge probably expects you to convert that two call recursion into a two variable iteration.